# clang-tidy can't find #include <cstddef>

Tags: cmake, clang-tidy

I am running clang-tidy checks using cmake version 3.20.0-rc1 on Windows 10.
My project builds using GNU 8.3.0.
Sadly I get the error

```
error: 'cstddef' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include <cstddef>
```

clang-tidy info:

> LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
> LLVM version 12.0.0
> Optimized build.
> Default target: i686-pc-windows-msvc
> Host CPU: skylake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[clang-diagnostic-error]` is basically a compiler error coming from the clang backend.

Clang-tidy needs an AST (abstract syntax tree) - your code has to be compileable by clang compiler in order to generate an AST. Only then will clang-tidy analyze your code.

Get your code to compile by clang instead of GCC and you should find the source of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I will try it soon.
Sadly never used clang before and I have problems with the not delivered libraries for Windows.